# Logic Error Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Biblioteca {
    String[] libros = {"Odisea", "Diccionario", "Historia", "Sociales", "Biblia"};
    String nombre;
    Boolean[] disponible = {true, true, true, true, true};

    public Biblioteca(String a, String nombre) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < libros.length; i++) {
            if (a == libros[i] && disponible[i] == true) {
                System.out.println("El libro esta disponible");
                disponible[i] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The vector `disponible[i]` changes, but it does not change if I use the method with another object in the main class, example

```
Biblioteca b1 = new Biblioteca("Bible", "Ana");
Biblioteca b2 = new Biblioteca("Bible", "Jacke");
```

The problem is say the name and the book that you want, you have to see if the book is available and if it is, the book wont be available anymore and you save the name of the user in a file.  And the same process to return the book , if the file exists ,you put available the book again and deleted the file.

The array of the books contains five

```
libros = {"Odisea", "Diccionario", "Historia", "Sociales", "Biblia"};
```

Someone can help me, please?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: @Aify the question is why the 'disponible' array doesn't change ...I think

Comment: @Alejandro by using a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Because your class declares instance variables only you are creating fresh copies of
those variables for each object. Therefore the state of your book library is not maintained.

You need to model your class in such a way that you reference the same data structure across all objects. That is static variables. Make disponible static.

Read up on the difference between instance variables and static variables.

Comment: For the OP, check the singleton pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Can you help me ? I need to create another class. or what?

Comment: THANKS YOU ,I FINALLY DID IT